# How to create a Initializer for layers.batch_normalization?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, initializer, batch-normalization

The default `beta_initializer` for `layers.batch_normalization` is: `tf.zeros_initializer()`.

Is it possible to create a new initializer with an arbitrary value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the list of [built-in initializers](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_guides/python/state_ops#Sharing_Variables). The one that interests you is [`tf.constant_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer):

> Initializer that generates tensors with constant values.